# jQuery plugin set image src relative to the plugins location

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having some trouble creating a jQuery plugin that uses an image from the plugin itself.

Let's say I have the following structure

- foobar

  - assets

    - images

      - fooBar.png
  - js

    - foo_bar.js

---

And I created a plugin like this.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.fooBar = function () {
    let image_foo = '<img id="leFoo" style="display: none" src="../assets/images/fooBar.png"/>';
    $('body').append(image_foo);
  }
});
```

The plugin is being added to the site correctly and I can call the function like this: `jQuery('body').fooBar();`. The issue is that it is trying to fetch the image from the current path. So if I was on `https://example.com/some/long/path/here.html`
It would then try to fetch the image like so `https://example.com/some/long/path/assets/images/fooBar.png`

While the actual location could be different depending on where the library is being placed. Is there a way to dynamically fetch the path from the library location?

Comment: Is there only one assets/images directory regardless of page location? Try removing the leading dots to make it absolute path  .. `src="/assets/images..."`

Comment: In the plugin folder "foobar" yes. I can imagine that some sites have multiple directories. To your edit, `src="/assets/images...` won't be possible since the plugin could be placed in someones site in a different location. E.g. `mycool_site/plugins/jquery/foobar`

Comment: OK I think I get it, is relative to where plugin is. Might need to set an option for path to images in plugin

Comment: Like this then perhaps? `jQuery('body').fooBar('/plugins/jquery')` where the plugin itself would then use `'/' + location + '/assets/images/fooBar.png'` ? (location obviously being taken from the options being passed to the function).

Comment: Something like that. Is more common for jQuery plugins to pass in an object.... `jQuery('body').fooBar({imageRoot:'/plugins/jquery/'})`. Then that object can have numerous options user can override if needed